# unable to upload cookbook from knife to chef-server

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I am running open source chef server on ubuntu ec2 instance. I am trying to upload the cookbook from my workstation using knife to chef-server, I am getting following error

```
/home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (SocketError)
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:66:in `timeout'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:172:in `transmit'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/resource.rb:76:in `put'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:151:in `block in uploader_function_for'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:25:in `call'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in setup_worker_threads'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:24:in `loop'
    from /home/jeevan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/chef-11.6.0/lib/chef/cookbook_uploader.rb:24:in `block (2 levels) in setup_worker_threads'
```

when I ran the same command in the verbose mode I figured out knife or workstation or chef-client installed on my laptop is trying to connect to the private ip of the ubuntu ec2 instance.

How do I prevent the knife to stop connecting to private ip of the ubuntu ec2 instance and connect to the sub-domain/domain or elastic ip of the server.

Kindly help me out

Comment: the URL of chef server is configured in your `~/.chef/knife.rb`. make sure the value of entry `chef_server_url` is the URL to your ec2 instance. it happens when you register your workstation in this chef server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check how you configured **chef_server_url** in your [chef configuration file](http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_knife.html).

You may want to configure the fqdn to your server instead of just the hostname.

for example if your machine is called **myhserver.mycompany.com** then if you configured (in your knife.rb)

> chef_server_url        'myserver:8080'

then your server may be resolved to the private ip, and if you configred

> chef_server_url        'myserver.mycompany.com:8080'

Then it may be resolved to your public IP. it depends how your DNS is configured.

Note: you can also consider configuring **chef_server_url** to point to your IP (instead of hostnames/fqdn).